# Jsoup Parsing html but i lost data

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using jsoup lib to get some data from html file. i am using Volley for the request and jsoup to get the data. But when i log.e the body of html i can that i lost data tha there are out of

but inside of .

Url: http://zodia123.gr/widget4_show.php#

My Code:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response, charset);
        Log.e("Web", "Response body :" + doc.body());
    }
```

Lost data:

```
<p></p>Βάζετε νέες προκλήσεις μπροστά σας και νιώθετε έτοιμοι να εντυπωσιάσετε με τις επιδόσεις σας. Εσείς που είστε μόνοι θα κάνετε πολλές καινούργιες γνωριμίες αλλά δεν αποκλείεται να γυρίσετε πίσω σε μια σχέση του πρόσφατου παρελθόντος. Οι αδέσμευτοι του ζωδίου, θα νιώσετε μπερδεμένοι γιατί θα δείτε πρόσωπα του παρελθόντος που θα σας αναστατώσουν και συγχρόνως θα γοητευτείτε από καινούργιες παρουσίες που θα μπουν στη ζωή σας. 
        </div>
```

Log.e output :

```
E/Web: Response body :<body> <!-- --> <div class="widget-border with-img" style="text-align:center;width:320px;height:450px"> <div class="scrollable"> <div class="items"> <div class="item"> <img src="/images/widget_signs/aries.png"> <h5>ÎÏÎ¹ÏÏ</h5> </div> <div class="item"> <img src="/images/widget_signs/taurus.png"> <h5>Î¤Î±ÏÏÎ¿Ï</h5> </div> <div class="item"> <img src="/images/widget_signs/gemini.png">
```

--Edit--

Volley Response:

```
...
 <div class="item">
   <img src="/images/widget_signs/aries.png">
   <h5>ÎÏÎ¹ÏÏ</h5>
   <p></p>ÎÎ¬Î¶ÎµÏÎµ Î½Î­ÎµÏ ÏÏÎ¿ÎºÎ»Î®ÏÎµÎ¹Ï Î¼ÏÏÎ¿ÏÏÎ¬ ÏÎ±Ï ÎºÎ±Î¹ Î½Î¹ÏÎ¸ÎµÏÎµ Î­ÏÎ¿Î¹Î¼Î¿Î¹ Î½Î± ÎµÎ½ÏÏÏÏÏÎ¹Î¬ÏÎµÏÎµ Î¼Îµ ÏÎ¹Ï ÎµÏÎ¹Î´ÏÏÎµÎ¹Ï ÏÎ±Ï. ÎÏÎµÎ¯Ï ÏÎ¿Ï ÎµÎ¯ÏÏÎµ Î¼ÏÎ½Î¿Î¹ Î¸Î± ÎºÎ¬Î½ÎµÏÎµ ÏÎ¿Î»Î»Î­Ï ÎºÎ±Î¹Î½Î¿ÏÏÎ³Î¹ÎµÏ Î³Î½ÏÏÎ¹Î¼Î¯ÎµÏ Î±Î»Î»Î¬ Î´ÎµÎ½ Î±ÏÎ¿ÎºÎ»ÎµÎ¯ÎµÏÎ±Î¹ Î½Î± Î³ÏÏÎ¯ÏÎµÏÎµ ÏÎ¯ÏÏ ÏÎµ Î¼Î¹Î± ÏÏÎ­ÏÎ· ÏÎ¿Ï ÏÏÏÏÏÎ±ÏÎ¿Ï ÏÎ±ÏÎµÎ»Î¸ÏÎ½ÏÎ¿Ï. ÎÎ¹ Î±Î´Î­ÏÎ¼ÎµÏÏÎ¿Î¹ ÏÎ¿Ï Î¶ÏÎ´Î¯Î¿Ï, Î¸Î± Î½Î¹ÏÏÎµÏÎµ Î¼ÏÎµÏÎ´ÎµÎ¼Î­Î½Î¿Î¹ Î³Î¹Î±ÏÎ¯ Î¸Î± Î´ÎµÎ¯ÏÎµ ÏÏÏÏÏÏÎ± ÏÎ¿Ï ÏÎ±ÏÎµÎ»Î¸ÏÎ½ÏÎ¿Ï ÏÎ¿Ï Î¸Î± ÏÎ±Ï Î±Î½Î±ÏÏÎ±ÏÏÏÎ¿ÏÎ½ ÎºÎ±Î¹ ÏÏÎ³ÏÏÏÎ½ÏÏ Î¸Î± Î³Î¿Î·ÏÎµÏÏÎµÎ¯ÏÎµ Î±ÏÏ ÎºÎ±Î¹Î½Î¿ÏÏÎ³Î¹ÎµÏ ÏÎ±ÏÎ¿ÏÏÎ¯ÎµÏ ÏÎ¿Ï Î¸Î± Î¼ÏÎ¿ÏÎ½ ÏÏÎ· Î¶ÏÎ® ÏÎ±Ï. 
 </div>
 <div class="item">
...
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest you put some logs inside Volley too to see if the actual data is returned before passing to Jsoup.

Comment: Volley response Perfect . i Will post here my Volley response

Comment: @WenChao i edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, the wrong method is used here. In your code, this method is used:

[parse(String html, String baseUri)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

whereas you want to use one of the following methods:

- [parse(File in, String charsetName)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.File-java.lang.String-)
- [parse(File in, String charsetName, String baseUri)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri, Parser parser)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.parser.Parser-)

On the other hand, the url content is encoded in UTF-8. Jsoup defaults to this encoding automatically. So try this instead:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
    Log.e("Web", "Response body :" + doc.select("div.item > h5 ~ *").size());
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the Encode ... the problem is that jsoup lost Data that there out of <p></p>

Comment: @Cliff Did you try the small suggested change?

Comment: again i lost data... :)  <div class="item"> <img src="/images/widget_signs/aries.png"> <h5>ÎÏÎ¹ÏÏ</h5> </div>

Comment: @Cliff Which version of Jsoup are you using?

Comment: compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'

Comment: i dont know if i help... On Debug mode i check the 'response value' and i see all the code of hml but when i make    Log.e("Volley", "Response :"+response); i lost the data o my console... The data that is lost is one line : <p></p>ÎÎ¬Î¶ÎµÏÎµ Î½Î­ÎµÏ ÏÏÎ¿ÎºÎ»Î®ÏÎµÎ¹Ï ......

Comment: On Debug Mode : https://i.imgsafe.org/df1ea09.jpg  and on Logcat : https://i.imgsafe.org/092beaf.jpg

Comment: @Cliff I have post a new version of the `onResponse` method. Can you try it?

Comment: i have tried your code and the responde is : E/Web: Response body :12. You know that i need the next line after <h5> :) i mean i need the data after <p></p> data </div>

Comment: @Cliff This means Jsoup has successfully found at least the `p` elements. Continue your work no matter what Logcat prints...